# Remove imgur from uploading images

Tags: php, laravel, api, backend, imgur

A few months ago a friend of mine added in my cms created in laravel the upload of images via imgur, only that I would like to remove it, on the cms however the images are saved (locally) I would like to remove the upload on imgur and I would like to stay the images locally

```
public function imageProfile(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $rules = array(
            'profile-image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:8192|dimensions:min_width=160,min_height=160',
        );

        $customMessages = [
            'profile-image.required' => 'E\' richiesta una immagine per cambiare immagine di profilo.',
            'profile-image.image' => 'Devi inserire un immagine valida.',
            'profile-image.mimes' => 'L\'immagine inserita non ha un formato adatto.',
            'profile-image.dimensions' => 'L\'immagine deve essere minimo 160x160.',
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $customMessages);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['success' => false, 'error' => $this->validationErrorsToString($validator->errors())]);
        }

        if ($request->hasFile('profile-image')) {
            $number = mt_rand(1,1000000);
            $image = $request->file('profile-image');
            $name = $user->username.'-'.Carbon::now()->toDateString().'-'.$number.'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $destinationPath = public_path('/uploads/profile');
            $imagePath = $destinationPath. "/".  $name;
            $image->move($destinationPath, $name);      

            $image = Imgur::setHeaders([
            'headers' => [
                'authorization' => 'Client-ID MY CLIENT ID',
                'content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            ]
            ])->setFormParams([
                'form_params' => [
                    'image' => URL::to("/").'/uploads/profile/'. $name,
                ]
            ])->upload(URL::to("/").'/uploads/profile/'. $name);

            \File::delete('uploads/profile/' .$name);


            $user->image_profile = $image->link();
            $user->save();
            $html =  $image->link();



            return response()->json(['success' => true, 'html' => $html, 'image' => $image->link()]);
        }
    }
```

My server is running Ubuntu 16.04 + Laravel 5.5

Best Regards

Comment: If I understand correctly, you'd like to remove the image from Imgur after it's been uploaded to your server. If that's the case then you'll need to use Imgur's API to remove the image from Imgur's servers: https://api.imgur.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will only upload photo to your local directory.

```
public function imageProfile(Request $request)
    {
        $user = Auth::user();
        $rules = array(
            'profile-image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif|max:8192|dimensions:min_width=160,min_height=160',
        );

        $customMessages = [
            'profile-image.required' => 'E\' richiesta una immagine per cambiare immagine di profilo.',
            'profile-image.image' => 'Devi inserire un immagine valida.',
            'profile-image.mimes' => 'L\'immagine inserita non ha un formato adatto.',
            'profile-image.dimensions' => 'L\'immagine deve essere minimo 160x160.',
        ];

        $validator = Validator::make(Input::all(), $rules, $customMessages);

        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return response()->json(['success' => false, 'error' => $this->validationErrorsToString($validator->errors())]);
        }

        if ($request->hasFile('profile-image')) {
            $number = mt_rand(1,1000000);
            $image = $request->file('profile-image');
            $name = $user->username.'-'.Carbon::now()->toDateString().'-'.$number.'.'.$image->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $destinationPath = public_path('/uploads/profile');
            $imagePath = $destinationPath. "/".  $name;
            $image->move($destinationPath, $name);  

            // remove this commented portion
            // $image = Imgur::setHeaders([
            // 'headers' => [
            //     'authorization' => 'Client-ID MY CLIENT ID',
            //    'content-type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            // ]
            // ])->setFormParams([
            //     'form_params' => [
            //         'image' => URL::to("/").'/uploads/profile/'. $name,
            //     ]
            // ])->upload(URL::to("/").'/uploads/profile/'. $name);

            // \File::delete('uploads/profile/' .$name);


            // $user->image_profile = $image->link();
            // $user->save();
            // $html =  $image->link();

            // update this portion to

            $user->image_profile = $imagePath;
            $user->save();
            $html =  $imagePath;



            // return response()->json(['success' => true, 'html' => $html, 'image' => $image->link()]);
            // also update this portion to
            return response()->json(['success' => true, 'html' => $html, 'image' => $imagePath]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: It works! But when I upload an image he has to take the directory "uploads/profile" instead he sets me "/var/www/awbeta/aw/public/uploads/profile/" and obviously the images don't start as I can solve?

Comment: for this, you have to change 2 things. first,
**first, change public_path('/uploads/profile') to '/uploads/profile'** 


and second, where you use the image src, change them to, **{{asset($user->image_profile)}}**

Comment: Okay done. 
`$destinationPath = public_path ('/uploads/profile');`

Comment: Nothing, even if I change the public_patch always leads to the same directory "/var/www/awbeta/aw/public/uploads/profile/"
I also changed the image src
`<img class="img-responsive" id="imageProfile" src="{{asset($user->image_profile)}}">`

Comment: upload a new photo and update?
It should shows like https://your.domain/uploads/profile/..

Comment: I don't understand .. I followed your steps `$destinationPath = public_path ('/uploads/profile');` `<img class="img-responsive" id="imageProfile" src="{{asset($user->image_profile)}}">`

Comment: obviously the directory of the images is found in "/var/www/awbeta/aw/public/uploads/profile" but obviously they are directory not accessible via web, it must directly take the images on "/uploads/profile"

Comment: `public_path ('/uploads/profile');` should be removed. and it will be `'/uploads/profile'`

Comment: With `$destinationPath = '/uploads/profile'` The logs give me this error: `[2019-06-16 20:10:48] production.ERROR: syntax error, unexpected '$imagePath' (T_VARIABLE) `

Comment: This error is on line 501 that is: `$imagePath = $destinationPath. "/".  $name;`

Comment: you must forgot, `;` colon.

Comment: Thank you so much it works!
I would have the same problem with the profile cover, could you help me? I would really appreciate it, the system is almost the same, and I would like to do the same thing as the profile image, ie save it locally

Comment: I think you should try by yourself. You already have an appropriate way. If you fails then, next will be next. :)

Comment: Hi @BoomToast if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.